# How can I layer a div with a semi-transparent image under one div and over another?

Tags: html, css

View my site here:
http://christinetynes.net/wp/about/

What I'm trying to do is have that wavy vine image go all the way across the top of the page, 100% width, underneath the header logo and navigation bar. It is 960px, but the edges line up so it repeats. The vine is a .png with a solid gray background on top and a transparent background underneath (you can see this if you click on the links to other pages).

I can't figure out how to do this... I have a div with the vine on the bottom and tried giving the logo and navigation a negative margin, but then the vine doesn't sit on top of the large photos, even when I change the z-index. How can I get the vine to repeat across the page, while still having it be layered over the large photos on each page? Those photos along with all the page content are within a 960px container div. Feel free to look at code in the inspector.

Comment: post code here not links to sites. if your site changes it is no help to future users. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since  you didn't post any code I played with Firebug and got this effect:

[image]

by altering your css in your `#vineheader` to look like this:

```
#vineheader {
   background: url("http://christinetynes.net/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/vine.png") repeat-x scroll center bottom #F0F0F0;
   margin-top: -40px;
   padding-top: 20px;
   position: relative;
   top: 80px;
   z-index: -1;
}
```

Hope this helps.